# Declaring a pointer to a struct

Tags: pointers, go

I'm confused because there seem to be two ways to initialize a pointer to a struct in the go language and they appear to me to be somewhat opposite in logic.

```
var b *Vertex
var c &Vertex{3 3}
```

Why does one use a * and the other use a & if b and c have the same resulting type?  My apologies for not adequately understanding the posts already up related to this topic.

I am also not yet straight on the implications of "receivers" in this context.  The terminology I am familiar with is "reference to (a)" or "pointer to (a)" or "address of (a)" and "de-reference of" or "value at address".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to declare a pointer to a `struct` and assign values to the `struct` fields. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func main() {
    {
        var pv *Vertex
        pv = new(Vertex)
        pv.X = 4
        pv.Y = 2
        fmt.Println(pv)
    }

    {
        var pv = new(Vertex)
        pv.X = 4
        pv.Y = 2
        fmt.Println(pv)
    }

    {
        pv := new(Vertex)
        pv.X = 4
        pv.Y = 2
        fmt.Println(pv)
    }

    {
        var pv = &Vertex{4, 2}
        fmt.Println(pv)
    }

    {
        pv := &Vertex{4, 2}
        fmt.Println(pv)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
&{4 2}
&{4 2}
&{4 2}
&{4 2}
&{4 2}
```

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

[Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)

[Address operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

[Allocation](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation)

[Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

Receivers are used for methods. For example, v is the receiver for the Vertex Move Method.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func NewVertex(x, y float64) *Vertex {
    return &Vertex{X: x, Y: y}
}

func (v *Vertex) Move(x, y float64) {
    v.X = x
    v.Y = y
}

func main() {
    v := NewVertex(4, 2)
    fmt.Println(v)
    v.Move(42, 24)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Output:

```
&{4 2}
&{42 24}
```

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Method sets](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

[Method declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)

[Calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

[Method expressions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)

[Method values](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)

Answer (score 1):

`var c = &Vertex{3, 3}` (you do need the `=`) is declaring a struct and then getting the reference to it (it actually allocates the struct, then gets a reference (pointer) to that memory).

`var b *Vertex` is declaring b as a pointer to Vertex, but isn't initializing it at all. You'll have a nil pointer.

But yes, the types are the same.

You can also do:

```
var d *Vertex
d = &Vertex{3,3}
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  What I'm gathering is that the * operator on a type isn't the de-reference operator I was assuming but more like a pointer operator to a nil instance whereas & is a pointer operator to an initialized instance.  Is that right?

Comment: * does do dereference, but it's often not required, because when you call functions using a pointer, it automatically dereferences if needed. When you pass things as parameters to functions is when the type matters, and you might need to pass a reference or a pointer. When you define the type of a parameter while declaring a function, you should use * as well (if you want a pointer to be passed in), because that defines a pointer to Vertex.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Wes Freeman mentioned, you also asked about receivers.

Let say you have this:

```
type Vertex struct {
} 

func (v *Vertex) Hello() {
   ... do something ...
}
```

The Vertex struct is the receiver for the func Hello().  So you can then do:

```
d := &Vertex{}
d.Hello()
```

Comment: Receivers do not have to be `struct`s. For example, if we have `type Integer int` then we can have a receiver of type `Integer` or `*Integer`.

Comment: @peterSO  Thank you for pointing that out. I modified my statement.